# Python's turtle.getscreen() loses the color of the screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I save an image with getcanvas().postscript(file="xxx.eps"), the shape of the turtle, the pen color, the turtle color, the drawing done by the turtle, are all saved correctly.  But the color of the screen is white, no matter what it's been set as. How can I retain the color that I've set?  Here's a tiny example, where I default everything except screen color:

```
trl = turtle.Turtle()         #Request a turtle to draw with
window=turtle.Screen()        #Request a screen
window.bgcolor('green')       #Set its color
trl.forward(100)              #Draw line
ws = trl.getscreen()
ws.getcanvas().postscript(file="cline.eps")
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has pointed me at question 13537483 where this question has already been posed. The conclusion seems to be that the save was deliberately set this way so as not to waste ink on colored backgrounds: this changes my problem; [posting directions seem to indicate that I should post it as a separate question, but since I'm here already]:

I am really interested in saving the screen output to disk, not in printing it. I only found the .eps option in my search, and I now see that it's not what I need. Is there a way that I can write the output to tiff or pdf or jpg or...?